# Is it possible to get a graph for Taiwan water area

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, geography

I tried to get a graph for water area in Taiwan, but somehow it doesn't seem to work:

```
CountryData[Entity["Country", "Taiwan"], "WaterArea"]
```

And now if I want to get the graph:

```
DateListPlot[
 CountryData["Taiwan", {{"WaterArea"}, {2015, 2021}}]]
```

It doesn't work.

Does anybody know if it is even possible to get this data from Wolfram in a graph?

Comment: My first guess is that the information is currently not available through `CountryData`.  Your syntax is correct, which you can confirm by replacing "WaterArea" with "Population".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figuring out what data is available through Wolfram's knowledge base functions is not trivial.  Here's the method I used to determine what temporal data is available for Taiwan.

```
p = CountryData["Properties"];
l = Table[{i, 
    Quiet@Check[CountryData["Taiwan", {i, All}], 
      Missing["NotAvailable"]]}, {i, p}];
lt = Select[l, #[[2]] =!= Missing["NotAvailable"] &];
Length@lt (* 25 *)
```

Then with something like `Quiet@Animate[Check[DateListPlot[lt[[x, 2]], PlotLabel -> lt[[x, 1]]],  "OPPS"], {x, 1, Length@lt, 1}]` we can quickly visualize what temporal data are available:

[image]

Comment: Do you maybe know how I could have the graphs that show in your answer automatically be compared with the net profit of let's say Nvidia company or maybe stock price of Nvidia company?

Comment: @vlc Assuming that the Nvidia data are available through FinancialData or something similar, the two datasets could be transposed to form your desired plot.  You will need to do a bit of post-processing of the data as there is unlikely any built-in function that will do everything in one step.